# Bootstrap 4 grid not aligning

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap has its own grid system and I want to utilize it as much as I can so that I can minimize any custom CSS.

I have the code below wherein I have a couple of `row` classes here, you can see here that the first row is not aligning with the rest of the row. Is there any way that I can make this aligned?

You can also view it here on codepen https://codepen.io/aceraven777/pen/zYZMpEd

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="bg-red">
                This is a content
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="bg-red">
                This is a content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8 row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="bg-red">
                    This is a content
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="bg-red">
                    This is a content
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="bg-red">
                    This is a content
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="bg-red">
                    This is a content
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="bg-red">
                    This is a content
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="bg-red">
                    This is a content
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="bg-red">
                    This is a content
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="bg-red">
                    This is a content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="bg-red">
                This is a content
                This is a content
                This is a content
                This is a content
                This is a content
                This is a content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are combining rows and columns together in one div. With bootstrap you cant combine rows and columns as there are some conflicting css. Just split this div `<div class="col-8 row">` into two seperate divs.

```html
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="bg-red">This is a content</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="bg-red">This is a content</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="bg-red">This is a content</div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="bg-red">This is a content</div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="bg-red">This is a content</div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="bg-red">This is a content</div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="bg-red"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```